# Or sql statement using MY_MODEL by avenirer

Tags: codeigniter

Can anybody please help me achieving the result and solve my problem. I'm working in codeigniter where i want to fetch records from a mysql database using OR statement. I'm using custom model extension by Avenirer. I want to know how to use or operator in where function of this MY_MODEL:

https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model/blob/version-3.0/core/MY_Model.php

Comment: You can use it as you use normal query builder: `$this->db->or_where('whatever');` as example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

You use *or_where*

```
$this->db->where('column1', 'like');
$this->db->or_where('column2', 'like');
```

or you can write both in a *where*

```
$this->db->where("(column1='like' OR column2='like')");
```

Hope it helps you out.

I can't give you an exact answer for your code, because I don't know exactly where the error is. If you could write the line to it, that would be useful.

Comment: I am using custom query builder using MY_MODEL by avenirer. It builds query this way:
`$this->Table_Model->where('field_name','value')->get_all();`
Please guide me in use of this MY_MODEL because using standard query builder , the result output is to in same format as using MY_MODEL

Comment: The way I see it, all you have to do is use one where, like:

$this->Tabel_Model->where('field_name','value')->get();

And not:

$this->Table_Model->where('field_name','value')->get_all()

If that doesn't work, I need your code, maybe the error is in another place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer by studying the code in MY_MODEL file. 
The right way to write where with OR clause was to use their special syntax. 
As per the code in the file MY_MODEL, it states the supported arguments for where function, which are:

`where($field_or_array = NULL, $operator_or_value = NULL, $value = NULL, $with_or = FALSE, $with_not = FALSE, $custom_string = FALSE)`

Setting the 4th argument true will change the final syntax to OR statement.
Right statement in my case will be:

`$this->Table_model->where('field1','value1')->where('field2','value2',null,true)->get_all();`

This statement will be processed to following SQL statement.

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 'field1'='value1' or 'field2'='value2'`

Thanks all for their cooperation.